# Google maps not showing in IE/FF

Tags: javascript, html

This map works perfectly in chrome but appears like this in IE and FF;

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nMGrh.jpg

This is the code I have:

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;key=AIzaSyBTbIpaaV72BfdUL3aOSU8dER1oUaso79o"></script>

<script type="text/JavaScript">
    //<![CDATA[
        function addLoadEvent(func) 
        {
            var oldonload = window.onload;

            if (typeof window.onload != 'function')
            {
            window.onload = func;
            } 
            else 
            {
            window.onload = function() 
                    {
                            if (oldonload) 
                            {
                            oldonload();
                            }
                    func();
                    }       
            }
        }
        addLoadEvent(load);
        //]]>
    </script>

    <div id="map" style="width:970px; height:600px; border: 1px solid #000; margin:0 auto;" ></div>
```

Comment: try with   <script src="https://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;key=AIzaSyBTbIpaaV72BfdUL3aOSU8dER1oUaso79o"></script> instead of <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;key=AIzaSyBTbIpaaV72BfdUL3aOSU8dER1oUaso79o"></script>

Answer (score 1):

try with

```
<script src="https://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;key=AIzaSyBTbIpaaV72BfdUL3aOSU8dER1oUaso79o"></script> 
                 ^
```

instead of

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;key=AIzaSyBTbIpaaV72BfdUL3aOSU8dER1oUaso79o"></script>
```

Comment: Sorry, but what did you change?

Comment: No change unfortunately.

Comment: https instead of http